# Fetching part of one to many property using Spring Data Projections

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson, jpql

I want to return a tuple of `Parent.id` field and `List<Child.id>`.

---

`Parent`:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long parentId;

    //we actually use Set and override hashcode&equals
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(Child child) {

        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(Child child) {

        child.setParent(null);
        children.remove(child);
    }

    public Long getParentId() {

        return id;
    }

    public List<Child> getReadOnlyChildren() {

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
    }
}
```

`Child`:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long childId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Parent parent;

    public Long getChildId() {

        return id;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {

        return parent;
    }

    /**
     * Only for usage in {@link Parent}
     */
    void setParent(final Parent parent) {

        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The Spring Data Projection:

```
import java.util.List;

interface IdAndChildrenIds {

    Long getParentId();

    List<ChildId> getChildren();
}

interface ChildId {

    Long getChildId();
}
```

The `ParentRepository` this is where problems begin:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long> {

    IdAndChildrenIds findIdAndChildrenIdsById(Long id);
}
```

But that doesn't work because the property doesn't comply with JavaBean standard (getter `getReadOnlyChildren` instead of `getChildren`), so I configured `ObjectMapper` to recognize private fields:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class HibernateConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().build();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper));
    }
}
```

Then, it still doesn't work because the property is `LAZY` initialized and it cannot be fetched outside a transaction (and because I wrote `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in `application.properties` due to that being a better practice). So, I must specify explicit `join` using query and also must use aliases so Spring Data recognizes the properties:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long> {

    @Query("select " +
           "    c.parent.parentId   as parentId, " +
           "    c.childId as childId" +
           "from Child c inner join a.parent p " +
           "where p.parentId=:id")
    IdAndChildrenIds findIdAndChildrenIdsById(@Param("id") long id);
}
```

But this again doesn't work `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements` because the specified `select` gives a list of tuples: `List<{parentId, childId}>`, while I want one tuple of `{parentId, List<childId>}`.

So, regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44921667/6166627) answer, I added `@Value("#{target.parentId}")` to `Long getParentId();`. But that did not have any effect in my case. I still get `NonUniqueResultException`.

Then, I tried changing the return value of the method from `IdAndChildrenIds` to `IdAndChildrenIds` just to see if the error goes away, even though that solution would not help. But that didn't work either:

```
Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAdvisorChainFactory and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

As I said, field visibility is already set to `ANY`.

---

Versions:

```
 - Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE
 - Spring Boot Starter Data JPA
 - Spring Boot Starter Web
 - Spring HATEOAS
```

Comment: `NonUniqueResultException` means the query returns more than one rows from the database but in your method you are accepting onls one entry. . You should change `IdAndChildrenIds` to `List<IdAndChildrenIds>`

Comment: @pvpkiran thanks for the answer but you probably did not read the end of the paragraph with the exception. I said that I know what this exception means and that I only need a single result

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @SuganthanMadhavanPillai I don't remember what exactly I did, but now I would create a custom repository method and manually select the above query (that returns `List<Tuple<Long, Long>>`; JPA sees it as `Object[]`) and then I transform it in-memory to the desired `Map<Long, List<Long>>`  (better some DTO of course). That way, I can keep the repository and the calling code clean.

Comment: @Sam, Can you please add your solution so that it will be beneficial for others.

Comment: @rajadilipkolli added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this now, weird that I want parent id and ids of its children while knowing the parent id already.

```java
interface ChildRepo{

  @org.spring...Query(value = "select id from children where parent_id = :parentId", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Long> findIdsByParentId(Long parentId);
}

@lombok.Value
class IdsDto{
  Long parentId;
  List<Long> childrenIds;

}

public IdsDto createTupleThing(Long parentId){
  return new IdsDto(parentId, childRepo.findIdsByParentId(parentId);
}
```

Comment: we are calling db twice, how to eradicate it?

Comment: why are you calling it twice I don't get it?

Comment: In the sample provided by you, first we are fetching the parentId in findIdsByParentId and then using childRepo you are fetching child values, which means calling db twice. We want to eradicate it.

Comment: Looking at something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/60641117/5557885 which is my way of solution.

Comment: There's only one call "**childRepo**.findIdsByParentId(parentId)". Presumably, you already know parent id